# Constraining "size per unit" in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two different sets of data which span different X values and intervals

For instance,

`A : spans from 0 to 100
B : spans from 1000 to 1200`

I want to create 2 different plots (one for each set), but in order to visually compare them, I want them to use the same "size per unit" (i.e. number of unit per pixel, assuming you do not re-size the plot) on the X axis.

By default, plot B will be the same total width as A, but with a "scale" twice as small (say 10 units per pixel instead of 5 units per pixel in A). 
What I'd like instead is both plot with 5 units per pixel but B with twice the width of A.

I tried looking for "scale" in matplotlib documentation, but that's something completely different (transformation function applied between actual data and displayed data).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT: so I kept looking, and I guess I could chose a size per unit and calculate the length of the interval spanned by my data myself, and then explicitly specify the width of the figure. But isn't there a built-in way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is 'Axis customization'. I don't have a working setup of matplotlib here to test it, but the method to use seems to be

```
YAxis::set_data_interval(min, max)
```

to set the vertical (typical value axis) limits on the displayed data.

Comment: isn't it the same as matplotlib.pyplot.ylim ? In that case, that is not what I am looking for. I already use ylim(min,max) to constrain height of the plots, but I still want to have the same "size per unit" on X axis.

Comment: I think I get it now. Yeah, YAxis will not help you there. This is a fairly rare requirement as usually several plots either refer to a similar X-range of data or just use different "size per unit".

Comment: The Xrange (Xmax - Xmin) is roughly similar. It can varies by a factor of 2 or 3, which is sufficiently small for the different plots to be "readable" even if they all use the same "size per unit".
The problem is, I have a rough idea of (Xmax - Xmin) but I don't know the actual Xmin (or Xmax), so I can't use xlim, unless I am mistaken.